# StackedXYAreaChart - displays wrong series number always

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have constructed a stackedXYAreaChart using the ChartFactory Utility. I am trying to generate a custom Tooltip. I observe a very weird output. My series 4 line is never visible and also the tooltips are never displayed. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Here's my code:

```
package test;


import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StackedXYAreaRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimePeriod;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset;

public class Test2
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TimeTableXYDataset dataset = new TimeTableXYDataset();
    for( int i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        TimePeriod period = new Millisecond();
        dataset.add(period, i, "Series 1");
        dataset.add(period, i + 5, "Series 2");
        dataset.add(period, i + 10, "Series 3");
                    dataset.add(period, i + 15 , "Series 4");
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart(
            "Sample Chart", "Time", "Size", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
            StackedXYAreaRenderer render = new StackedXYAreaRenderer();
            //render.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0, -3.0, 6.0, 6.0));
            render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(0, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
                            render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(1, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
                            render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(2, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
                            render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(3, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
                            chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(render);


            ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
                            panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(panel);
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new `StackedXYAreaRenderer`, modify the `StackedXYAreaRenderer2` created by the factory method, [`ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1916).

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
StackedXYAreaRenderer2 render = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) plot.getRenderer();
```

Alternatively, use the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1892) as a guide to creating a custom chart.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StackedXYAreaRenderer2;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimePeriod;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TimeTableXYDataset dataset = new TimeTableXYDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TimePeriod period = new Millisecond();
            dataset.add(period, i, "Series 1");
            dataset.add(period, i + 5, "Series 2");
            dataset.add(period, i + 10, "Series 3");
            dataset.add(period, i + 15, "Series 4");
        }

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart(
            "Sample Chart", "Time", "Size", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        StackedXYAreaRenderer2 render = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) plot.getRenderer();
        render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(0, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(1, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(2, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        render.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(3, new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(render);

        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely helps. One more question though - I need to display shapes at each data point. I am unable to do that. Any idea on that? @trashgod

Comment: `StackedXYAreaRenderer2` doesn't support shapes, as suggested [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117353); you'll need to create your chart using `StackedXYAreaRenderer`, which does.

Answer (score 0):

StackedXYAreaRenderer supports shapes. Use the renderer as :

```
StackedXYAreaRenderer render = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(StackedXYAreaRenderer.AREA_AND_SHAPES);
```

StackedXYAreaRenderer2 does not support shapes unfortunately.